# Is there a clean way to suppress summary()'s display of fixed effects (a factor variable)?

Tags: r

I am running a model with a factor variable which has a ton of levels as a way of accounting for fixed effects. I would like to see the standard summary() of that model, but the ton of rows for each factor level really bloat the table. Is there a neat way of getting summary() to not display the rows from the factor?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `broom` package - `tidy(your_model)` will give you a data frame of each term in the model and you can then subset it however you would like. You can also use `glance()` to get much of the other information included in the summary, without terms for each coefficient.